# GMT offset for date in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, datetime, timezone, timezone-offset

I need GMT offset for date only. I am using this method

```
double numberOfHours = (double)[timeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:date]/ 3600.0;
```

Actually in Berlin, Germany DST would be ON at 31st March, 2013 and time will change at 2:00 am. 
The problem is I want GMT offset using date only. If date = 31-3-2013 00:00:00 then it returns +1. it returns +2 after 31-3-2013 02:00:00. Is there any method/way I can get timezone offset without using time components?

Comment: no need to typecast both to double, any one will be fine. and 3600.0 will be double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to avoid using time components. you can use these methods

`nextDaylightSavingTimeTransition` and `daylightSavingTimeOffsetForDate:NSDate`

of `NSTimeZone` class.

Answer (score 1):

How about just changing the time on your date to the middle of the day and testing that instead?

But no, without any time components at all the date will default to midnight and you will get the (**correct for that time**) result of +1.

Comment: Time is changing(+1 to +2) at 31st March. I need +2 for 31st march without using time components.

Comment: Why would you think this is possible?  It's not a true statement.  For midnight on that day, it is +1.  Why can't you just add the time components on before you calculate?

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use an `NSDateFormatter` with a custom date format such as `@"zzz"`, which will return the timezone offset for a given `NSDate`.